# Android bootstrap : Need to pass the authToken to my request accept header

Tags: android, rest, authentication

Allright, I have been struggling in understanding this authentification process with this "template" [project](https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap) and just don't get it.

What I am trying to do is a basic sign in, so I can get my authorization token, I've done it before by using SharedPreference (never actually used AccountManager) and accessing it from my rest android client (via a custom SessionManager).

So far, I was able to get the first part done. I am able to get my authorization token.

**BoostrapAuthenticatorActivity.java:**

```
 /**
     * Called when response is received from the server for authentication
     * request. See onAuthenticationResult(). Sets the
     * AccountAuthenticatorResult which is sent back to the caller. Also sets
     * the authToken in AccountManager for this account.
     */

    protected void finishLogin() {
        final Account account = new Account(email, Constants.Auth.LZGO_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        if (requestNewAccount)
            accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);
        else
            accountManager.setPassword(account, password);
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        authToken = token;
        userToken = user;
        intent.putExtra(KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, userToken);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, Constants.Auth.LZGO_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        if (authTokenType != null
                && authTokenType.equals(Constants.Auth.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE))
            intent.putExtra(KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
        setAccountAuthenticatorResult(intent.getExtras());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

How do I have access to this value ? If you check this class,

**BootstrapServiceProvider.java:**

```
@Inject private ApiKeyProvider keyProvider;
@Inject private UserAgentProvider userAgentProvider;

/**
 * Get service for configured key provider
 * <p>
 * This method gets an auth key and so it blocks and shouldn't be called on the main thread.
 *
 * @return bootstrap service
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws AccountsException
 */
public BootstrapService getService() throws IOException, AccountsException {
    return new BootstrapService(keyProvider.getAuthKey(), userAgentProvider);
}
```

And finally, the provider:

**ApiKeyProvider.java:**

```
@Inject private Activity activity;
@Inject private AccountManager accountManager;

/**
 * This call blocks, so shouldn't be called on the UI thread
 *
 * @return API key to be used for authorization with a {@link com.android.lzgo.core.LzgoService} instance
 * @throws AccountsException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String getAuthKey() throws AccountsException, IOException {
    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture = accountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures(Constants.Auth.BOOTSTRAP_ACCOUNT_TYPE,
            Constants.Auth.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE, new String[0], activity, null, null, null, null);
    Log.d("ApiKeyProvider", "ApiKeyProvider= " + accountManagerFuture.getResult().getString(KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
    return accountManagerFuture.getResult().getString(KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
}
```

But this get me a null value! I'm at lost!

Comment: On this line:https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/donnfelker/android/bootstrap/authenticator/BootstrapAuthenticatorActivity.java#L258, are you getting a TOKEN back from your web service?

Comment: Yes. AS I said, I really get my token from my webservice (in AuthenticatorActivity) in the function finishLogin().

Comment: You have a log statement ins there, if you remove that, what happens?

Comment: @DonnFelker Do you have any recommendation on accessing the TOKEN in `RestAdapterRequestInterceptor`?

Comment: You can inject the AccountManager into the interceptor, then perform a AccountManager#peekAuthToken() for the user that is currently logged in. That should get your authToken.

Comment: Hi @DonnFelker is this still the method to get the AuthToken in the `RestAdapterRequestInterceptor` class?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the authtoken isn't getting applied correctly by `setAccountAuthenticatorResult(...)`, however I've had luck by adding the following `accountManager.setAuthToken(...)` call in `finishLogin()`

```
if (authTokenType != null
            && authTokenType.equals(Constants.Auth.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE)) {
        intent.putExtra(KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
        accountManager.setAuthToken(account, authTokenType, authToken);
}
```

Perhaps this is related to not using Parse.com as our backend?

Comment: Thanks Jon! It works as temporary solution.

However, I would like to know why authtoken was not applied at first.